# Algorithm to find the intersection of sorted sets

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, set-intersection

I have been looking over ways to find the intersection of two sorted sets that are more efficient than doing so iteratively. Eventually my searching brought me to this question: [intersection and union of n-arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253600/intersection-and-union-of-n-arrays-in-c/13254130#13254130) . However, I do not understand how the intersection of two sets is equal to the intersection of the intersection of two subsets. I want to try to figure out how to do the divide and conquer algorithm with recursion, but I can't understand how the example given would work.

More specifically, how would a divide and conquer algorithm ever work for two sets such as:

```
A = 1, 2, 3, 4
B = 3, 5, 6, 7
```

It doesn't seem like a divide and conquer algorithm would exist that would actually consistently find the intersection at 3.

Comment: How about a HashSet?

Comment: That link is about multiple sets intersection or union. For two sets I can't think of anything faster then iterating through the two sorted arrays, like [here](https://ideone.com/o4RdbV), which is O(N).

Answer (score 2):

> However, I do not understand how the intersection of two sets is equal
>   to the intersection of the intersection of two subsets.

That's not what your link is talking about (because it's wrong, as you recognized).

Finding the the intersection of a sorted set, ie. the common elements of two sorted arrays,
is not possible without at least iterating them. It won't get better than O(N).

Answer (score -1):

Between two arrays find one which last element is greater than the first element of other.

For example:

```
A = 1, 2, 3, 4
B = 3, 5, 6, 7
```

Select array `A`. Apply Binary search on `A` from right to left to find an element such that:

```
A[i] >= B[0]
```

Now use linear search from this two arrays:

```
A[i......n]
B[0......m]
```

Where `n` and `m` are the length of `A` and `B` respectively.

I think it has less complexity than linear search at first attempt.

Comment: a) The question is not about common subsequences, but just set intersections. That's a difference. b) No, your idea has not less complexity than `O(n)`